# Does JAXB support marshalling of ArrayList of ArrayList object

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

In our java application I need to save multiple set of values provided by user. To handle this data I am using ArrayList < ArrayList < Object > >. When I send this data to JAXB marshaller it is writing my XMLElementWrapper and XMLElement names but its not writing the content of the each XMLElement. In this each XMLElement should be inner ArrayList. When I Unmarshall, I get the same size of ArrayList but the inner ArrayList contents are empty with size of zero.

We have another single ArrayList < Object > implementaion in the same class which is working as expected while marshaling and Unmarshalling.

Where could I be going wrong in case when marshalling object of type ArrayList < ArrayList < Object > > ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if your main variable is a List that list could contain objects which are of type ArrayList themselves. So you may not need to define it as ArrayList, because you can define the same structure as ArrayList.

Another option you may try is to make another class that basically contains a list. Then your main class could just be an ArrayList, then YourClass could actually contain it's own list.

I would also recommend using List for this instead of ArrayList. When I first started Java I was using ArrayList also, but you want to use the more generic List interface. ArrayList and the other types implement the List interface, so you want to define your variables as List incase the type underneath ever changes.

Comment: Logan, can you please eloborate more on your first statement?

Comment: Based on what you're saying your variable looks like, to me that was the same as saying your main variable is an ArrayList<Object>. An array list of "objects", but your objects happen to be other ArrayLists, so instead of saying ArrayList<ArraList<Object>>, you can just say ArraList<Object>.

Comment: I went with your idea of implementing a class containing a list and use the new class object in my actual arraylist. It is working !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IdAdapter.class)
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> _dataSet = null;

private static class IdAdapter extends XmlAdapter<RowList, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
{

    @Override
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> unmarshal(RowList v)
            throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for(ColumnList myList:v.rowList)
        {
            list.add(myList.columnList);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public RowList marshal(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> v)
            throws Exception
    {
        RowList rowList = new RowList();
        for(ArrayList<String> innerList:v)
        {
            ColumnList myList = new ColumnList();
            myList.columnList = innerList;
            rowList.rowList.add(myList);
        }
        return rowList;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="RowList")
private static class RowList
{
    @XmlElement(name="RowValues")
    ArrayList<ColumnList> rowList = new ArrayList<SpoolDataSet.ColumnList>();
}

@XmlRootElement(name="ColumnList")
private static class ColumnList 
{
    @XmlElement(name="ColumnValues")
    ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I had done this for ArrayList> you can change the string to object as well.